# How to use submit button and choose to show table from listbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is my code I try to show which table matched with my list box
such as when I choose AIX from listbox and press button I want to show table1 
when i choose linux from listbox and press button i want to show table2 for example 
Can you help me how to write code for btton and choose table

Thank you

```
<select  name="System" id="System" style="font: 20pt AngsanaUPC "  onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
  <option value="" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC " >Choose system</option>
  <option value="AIX" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC " >AIX</option>
  <option value="LINUX" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC ">LINUX</option>
  <option value="SOLARIS" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC ">SOLARIS</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="font: 20pt AngsanaUPC ">Submit</button></td>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" width="100%">
</table>//table 1...

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example2" width="100%">
</table>//table 2....

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example3" width="100%">
</table>// table 3....
```

Comment: Please update this thread, either accepting an answer or providing detail via comment or edit or even self answer why it doesnt answer your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickMe(){

            $("table").hide();
            if($("#list").val()==="AIX"){
                $("#table1").show();
            }else if($("#list").val()==="LINUX"){
                $("#table2").show();
            }else if($("#list").val()==="SOLARIS"){
                $("#table3").show();
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="list">
    <option value="" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC " >Choose system</option>
    <option value="AIX" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC " >AIX</option>
    <option value="LINUX" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC ">LINUX</option>
    <option value="SOLARIS" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC ">SOLARIS</option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" onclick="javascript:clickMe()"/>
<br/>
<table id="table1" style="display:none;"><caption>Table 1</caption></table>
<br/>
<table id="table2" style="display:none;"><caption>Table 2</caption></table>

<br/>
<table id="table3" style="display:none;"><caption>Table 3</caption></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more clever approach that removes need for id="#" and some need for hardcoded management.

Use data-attributes to more easily match content, with checks in place mostly for help debugging if matching element not found.

Also uses more jquery-style approach, with $.on('click',function(){}); rather than inline script tag (which can be a pain to manage as site grows larger)

http://api.jquery.com/on/

https://api.jquery.com/click/ (shorthand/convenience function)

https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        // A $( document ).ready() block.
        $( document ).ready(function() {
          
            $("#submit").click(function(){

                // hide all switchable-tables
                $(".switchable-table").hide();
                
                // store ref to list element
                var $list = $("#list"); 
              
                // attempt to find the targetted table
                var $table = $(".switchable-table[data-switch-id='"+$list.val()+"']");
                
                // if found, show it
                if($table.length)
                {
                    $table.show();
                }
                // For debug only, can be disabled in production code
                else if($list.val() != "")
                {
                    console.error("no such table with matching data-switch-id as '"+$list.val()+"'", $list);
                }
            });

            

        });
    </script>
    <style type='text/css'>
    .switchable-table{ display:none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style='width:auto;margin:10px auto;'>
<select id="list">
    <option value="" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC " >Choose system</option>
    <option value="AIX" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC " >AIX</option>
    <option value="LINUX" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC ">LINUX</option>
    <option value="SOLARIS" style="font: 25pt AngsanaUPC ">SOLARIS</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
<br/>
<table class="switchable-table" data-switch-id="AIX" ><caption>Table 1</caption></table>

<table class="switchable-table" data-switch-id="LINUX"><caption>Table 2</caption></table>

<table class="switchable-table" data-switch-id="SOLARIS"><caption>Table 3</caption></table>

</body>
</html>
```